# Delay an action until current action is completed

Tags: hooks, actions

I have two actions that run when a post is updated. The issue is, the second function runs before the first has completed.

```
add_action('save_post', 'postUpdate', 10);

add_action('post_updated', ‘deleteCacheOnCloudfront ’, 1000, 3);
```

What is the best method to allow the first function to finish before the second action starts? Is there another hook that starts much later? In the meantime, I have set a one time cron to activate 5 seconds later, which I don't think is an elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the **third input argument** for the [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) callback, tells us whether it's an **update or not**. That could be helpful here, I think.

Taking your example as is, one suggestion could be:

```
add_action( 'save_post', function(  $post_ID, $post, $update ) {

   postUpdate( $post_ID );

   if ( $update ) {
       deleteCacheOnCloudfront( $post_ID, $post, $update );
   }

}, 10, 3 );
```

to run the `deleteCacheOnCloudfront()` function after the `postUpdate()` function on post updates only.

The `save_post` is a very general hook and there exists more specific ones, like `save_post_{post_type}` or other based on post status transitions, if you want to avoid running your code when .it doesn't need to.

The `postUpdate()` function name is very general, so you should consider using a namespace or a function prefix, to avoid possible name collisions.

Hopefully the `deleteCacheOnCloudfront()` runs quickly (short timeout) and will not let the user wait too long during each post save.

Hope it helps!

**Update:**

If `deleteCacheOnCloudfront()` depends on `$post_before` and `$post_after` we can consider:

```
/**
 * Run postUpdate() on save_post with priority 10.
 */
add_action( 'save_post', function(  $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
   postUpdate( $post_ID );
}, 10, 3 );

/**
 * Run deleteCacheOnCloudfront() on save_post with priority 11 when post is updated.
 */
add_action( 'post_updated', function(  $post_ID, $post_before, $post_after ) {
    add_action( 'save_post', 
        function(  $post_ID, $post, $update ) use ( $post_before, $post_after ) {
            deleteCacheOnCloudfront( $post_ID, $post_before, $post_after );
        }, 11, 3 );
}, 10, 3 );
```

where we pass data from the parent scope with the `use` keyword and use different priority to make sure `deleteCacheOnCloudfront()` (priority 11) runs after  `postUpdate()` (priority 10), within the `save_post` action.

We could also write this as a class instead, to move data across different hooks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I tried it with my setup, however, I realized I didn't get the results I needed. I actually use the arguments ($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before) that are available with the [post_updated](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated) hook. I think I'll have to stick with the one time cron method.

Comment: @Harv I updated the answer with another approach. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @birgire, I'll give this a try. While testing, I also realized that post_updated action occurs before save_post.

Comment: yes, that was the reason for the "hook twisting" in my updated answer, making sure both run in correct order when `save_post` fires, but with data from the  `post_updated` event available :-)